# Novice Life: Persistent trouble getting manim to run tikz

Tags: python, manim

I've watched videos on how to get manim to use tikz and followed several threads to fix issues, but nothing seems to help.

I've modified the tex_template.tex to include the requisite packages and changed the document class to "preview,dvisvgm".

I also modified tex_file_writing.py to include

```
"--libgs='/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.26_1/lib/libgs.dylib'"
```

in the dvi_to_svg section.

Despite all this I keep getting: Exception: Latex error converting to dvi. when trying to run

```
from manimlib.imports import *

class OutFit(Scene):
     def construct(self):

         TreeDiagram = TexMobject(r"""
            \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=5em, level 1/.style={sibling distance=5cm},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}, level 3/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=blue!20}]]
 \node  {Start}
    child { node {$s_1$} 
        child { node {$p_1$}
        child { node{$f_1$}}
        child {node{$f_2$}}}
    child { node {$p_2$}
        child { node{$f_1$}}
        child {node{$f_2$}}}}
    child { node {$s_2$} 
        child { node {$p_1$}
        child {node {$f_1$}}
        child {node {$f_2$}}}
    child { node {$p_2$}
        child {node {$f_1$}}
        child {node {$f_2$}}}}
    child { node {$s_3$}
        child { node {$p_1$}
        child {node {$f_1$}}
        child {node {$f_2$}}}
    child { node {$p_2$}
        child {node {$f_1$}}
        child {node {$f_2$}}}};

\end{tikzpicture}""")

        self.play(Write(TreeDiagram))
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `TexMobject` instead `TextMobject`? Please pay more attention before asking questions. Also you need the tikz package included in the manimlib/tex_template.tex file.

Anyway, doing this is not recommended, since you are abusing LaTeX functions, the best and most optimal is to create a class that generates the tree you want, but that class you will have to program yourself since it does not exist some class like this included in Manim, it is not difficult.

```py
class OutFit(Scene):
    def construct(self):

        tree_diagram = TextMobject(r"""
            \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=5em, level 1/.style={sibling distance=5cm},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}, level 3/.style={sibling distance=1cm}]
 \node  {Start}
    child { node {$s_1$} 
        child { node {$p_1$}
        child { node{$f_1$}}
        child {node{$f_2$}}}
    child { node {$p_2$}
        child { node{$f_1$}}
        child {node{$f_2$}}}}
    child { node {$s_2$} 
        child { node {$p_1$}
        child {node {$f_1$}}
        child {node {$f_2$}}}
    child { node {$p_2$}
        child {node {$f_1$}}
        child {node {$f_2$}}}}
    child { node {$s_3$}
        child { node {$p_1$}
        child {node {$f_1$}}
        child {node {$f_2$}}}
    child { node {$p_2$}
        child {node {$f_1$}}
        child {node {$f_2$}}}};

\end{tikzpicture}""",stroke_width=1,fill_opacity=0)
        
        tree_diagram.set_width(FRAME_WIDTH-1)

        self.play(Write(tree_diagram))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. It could have gone without the "pay more attention" comment though. Like I said, I'm new at this and learning as I go. In fact, I'm trying to learn it in somewhat of a hurry to make decent videos for students.

Comment: I understand that you are just learning, but you could have obtained the answer yourself by being more careful, this forum is made to contribute to the community, and your question does not contribute anything.

Comment: First of all, making the change you suggested didn't fix my problem. Second, I didn't know that would be the problem, since I though TexMobject would be used for LaTeX. Third, I didn't really know where else to ask. You could have just suggested a better place to ask the question.